# create multiple ppt slides with python

Tags: python, powerpoint

I want to print the slides based on array list. But somehow I don't grasp the logic. My code right now is like this

```
totalSheets = [0, 1, 2]
totalSlides = ['slide', 'slide2', 'slide3']


prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
for sheet, slide in zip(totalSheets, totalSlides):
    sheetExcel = excelFile.sheet_by_index(sheet)
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
```

I wrong at the slide one. I just thinking is it can doing like slide(n) and just do n += 1? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Uwoah you're right the prs and blank must be outside. Because the prs is also keep looping

Comment: It does not seem that any data is being added to `slide`. Presumably it is intended that the data come from `sheetExcel`. Could you describe in more detail what you are trying to put on the slides? I assume you are using [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html)?

Comment: Yes that's right. I get the data from excel. So i'm using xlrd and python-pptx

Comment: The next step would be to use something like `slide.shapes.add_picture(image_file, left, top, width=None, height=None)` to add an image obtained from the Excel sheet to the slide, or `slide.shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height)` to add a table, or any of the other [SlideShapeTree](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapeTree) methods.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to actually use random in the list, you can use this..

```
>>> import random
>>> totalSlides = ['slide', 'slide2', 'slide3']
>>> random.choice(totalSlides)
'slide3'
>>> random.choice(totalSlides)
'slide'
>>>
```

For mutiple on list, you can try this..

```
>>> import random
>>> totalSlides = ['slide', 'slide2', 'slide3']
>>> random.sample(totalSlides, len(totalSlides))
['slide2', 'slide3', 'slide']
>>> random.sample(totalSlides, len(totalSlides))
['slide3', 'slide', 'slide2']
>>> random.sample(totalSlides, len(totalSlides))
['slide2', 'slide', 'slide3']
>>> random.sample(totalSlides, len(totalSlides))
['slide3', 'slide2', 'slide']
>>>
```

Comment: But i think the page will be scatter. Because there have a page in the ppt

Comment: I don't see any request for randomly adding slides in the original post.